# Localhost authorization error iModel development

Tags: localhost, bentley-itwin

Going through the Bentley iTwin tutorial. First iModel in the Bentley cloud is built fine. However, the localhost on the development client gets an error right after "sign in". With below error message. The strange thing there is that the expanded directory "..../src/..." does not exist?

Unhandled Rejection (Error): SigninCallback error - failed to process signin request in callback using all known modes of token delivery: No state in response
The requested scope is invalid, unknown, malformed, or exceeds that which the client is permitted to request.
▼ 2 stack frames were expanded.
Function.handleSigninCallback
D:/iTwin/mvdbivo2/node_modules/@bentley/frontend-authorization-client/src/oidc/browser/BrowserAuthorizationCallbackHandler.ts:138
async Function.startup
D:/iTwin/mvdbivo2/node_modules/@bentley/imodeljs-frontend/src/WebViewerApp.ts:54
▲ 2 stack frames were expanded.

Comment: solved - seems to have been a firewall issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app's redirect uri matches **exactly** what has been registered at [https://developer.bentley.com/apps/spa/{your-client-id}](https://developer.bentley.com/apps/spa/%7Byour-client-id%7D).

For further questions/help please create a [discussion](https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/discussions) post on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your application is requesting a scope that it is not allowed to request. Make sure that the list of scopes your application requests is a subset of scopes configured for that application in [Applications page](https://developer.bentley.com/my-apps/)